# Show that for any non-zero vector in $\mathbb R^{n}$ we have $\bf ||\frac{1}{||u||}u|| = 1 $

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to

> Show that for any non-zero vector in $\mathbb R^{n}$ we have 
>   $$\bf ||\frac{1}{||u||}u|| = 1 $$

The author of the book provided way more elegant solution, but I wonder if my (uglier) attempt is correct

We evaluate $\bf \frac{1}{||u||}$:

$$\mathbf {\frac{1}{||u||}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}}$$

Thus

$$\bf \frac{1}{||u||}u = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{u_{1}}{\sqrt{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}} \\
    \frac{u_{2}}{\sqrt{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}}  \\
    \frac{u_{3}}{\sqrt{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}}   \\
\cdots
\\
\frac{u_{n}}{\sqrt{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}} 
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Finally 
$$\mathbf {||\frac{1}{||u||}u||} = \sqrt{\frac{u^{2}_{1}}{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}} + \frac{u^{2}_{2}}{u^{2}_{1} +  u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}} + .... +\frac{u^{2}_{n}}{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}} $$

Which means:
$$\mathbf {||\frac{1}{||u||}u||} = \sqrt{\frac{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} ... + u^{2}_{n}}{u^{2}_{1} + u^{2}_{2} + u^{2}_{3} .... + u^{2}_{n}}} = \sqrt{1} = 1 $$

Is it correct?

Comment: It is ugly, it works only for *that* specific norm (whereas the statement holds for *every* norm), but it is correct.

Comment: It is not ugly... it is horrible! A norm satisfies the nice equality $\Vert \lambda x\Vert = \vert \lambda \vert \Vert x \Vert$. You can try for the fun to demonstrate that for a specific $\lambda$, but doing so, you loose one spirit of mathematics which is generalization.

Comment: Just pull out $1/|u|,$ since it is a scalar, and the result is immediately obvious. Why go to all this tedium?